# Store a headerFilter with a persistent layout in Tabulator 3.5

Tags: filter, object-persistence, tabulator

I try to store my filter field into JSON object during the navigation process and get this Javascript issue in tabulator.js:

*Options Error - Tabulator does not allow options to be set after initialization unless there is a function defined for that purpose*

(java class)

```
    JsonObject configuracion = new JsonObject();
    configuracion.addProperty("height", "92%");
    configuracion.addProperty("tooltips", true);
    configuracion.addProperty("tooltipsHeader", true);


    configuracion.addProperty("persistentLayout", true); 
    configuracion.addProperty("layout","fitDataFill"); 
    configuracion.addProperty("persistenceMode", true); 
    configuracion.addProperty("persistenceID", myBandeja.getStrBandejaLogicaCaption().substring(0,4)); 
    configuracion.addProperty("persistentFilter", true);
    configuracion.addProperty("movableColumns", true);
    configuracion.addProperty("selectable", true);
    configuracion.addProperty("virtualDomBuffer",500);


    JsonObject fila = new JsonObject();
    JsonArray datasets = new JsonArray();
    for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : myTitleRow.entrySet()) {
                fila = new JsonObject();
                fila.addProperty("title", entry.getValue());
                fila.addProperty("field", entry.getValue());
                fila.addProperty("sorter", "string");
                fila.addProperty("headerFilter", "input");
                fila.addProperty("headerFilterPlaceholder", "Filtrar...");
                fila.addProperty("cellClick", "cellClickBandeja(e, cell);");

                datasets.add(fila);
        }
    configuracion.add("columns", datasets);
```

Some property is sorting wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you get that message it is either either one of two things.

You are trying to change an option after the Tabulator has been created using jQuery's ***option*** function which Tabulator does not allow.

Or because you are trying to re declare your table on an element that is already a Tabulator. If that is the case then you need to call the ***destroy*** function on the table before you create it again:

```
$("#example-table").tabulator("destroy");
```